# Mostrar valor capturado de una celda del DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagrid

Estoy intentado mostrar un valor en un TextBox siendo este capturado desde una celda de un DataGridView. 
Es decir, tengo un DataGridView que muestra títulos, al presionar uno de estos me gustaría saber como hago para mostrar en teléfono de ese título seleccionado en el DataGridView. Añado también, que el DataGridView se carga con una consulta de SqlServer.

Método para cargar el DataGridView:

```
public void llenaTitulo(){//carga el DataGridView = dtgTitulo
            try{
                string conn = "cadenadeconexion";
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn)){
                    conexion.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb group by titulo";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    conexion.Close();
                }
            }catch (SqlException ex){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: por DataGrid te refieres al DataGridView ?

Comment: Sí, disculpa que no lo haya escrito bien. Ya lo arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que el titulo es la key o codigo de la tabla que identifica al registro en la db, sino lo es entonces deberias crear una columna adicional donde este el id para poder buscar en base a esta y recuperar el telegono

Entonces usando el evento click de grid podrias ir a la db y consultar los demas datos

[DataGridView.CellContentClick Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?view=netframework-4.8)

algo como esto

```
private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var row = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
    var titutlo = row.Cells["titulo"].Value.ToString();


    string connstring = "connection string";  
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {  
        cn.Open();  

        string sql = "SELECT telefono FROM Tabla WHERE titulo =@titulo";  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@titulo", titulo);  

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

        if (reader.Read())  
        {  
            txttelefono.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["telefono"]);  
        }  

    } 
}
```

como veras tomas el valor de la columna titulo en el evento y usas ese dato para filtrar el registro en la tabla recuperando otro campo del mismo registro

Comment: Pues, me ha salido este error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.'`

Comment: Oh, me faltaba el con.Open(); disculpa

Comment: Vale, gracias ha servido. Pero, por algún motivo, cada vez que selecciono la celda el número queda siempre igual. Es decir, si selecciono la primer celda y luego la siguiente y así sucesivamente, el número no cambia.

Comment: valida que estes tomando las diferentes rows que seleccionas, cuando usas Rows[e.RowIndex], pon un breakpoint en el codigo y evalua que valor toma RowIndex